# R: in a line plot, how do you control the character used for each point (rather than for each series)?

Tags: r, plot, line-plot

I'm making a line plot with several lines/series. I'd like to have different characters for each point within a line/series.

The code I currently have is something like:

```
x <- rep(1:5, 4) * rep(rnorm(5), each = 4)
x <- matrix(x, 5, 4)
matplot(x, type = "b", pch = 1:4)
```

However, 'pch' only allows you change the character used for all points in one series. Is there any way to control each point individually?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plot` allows a different `pch` per point within a series; `matplot` doesn't (it only allows a different one for each series).
So you will have to use `plot`/`points`/`lines` instead of `matplot`.

e.g.

```
xs <- 1:nrow(x)
cols <- c('blue', 'red', 'black', 'green', 'yellow')

# set up empty plot with the right limits
matplot(x, type='n')
for (i in 1:ncol(x))
  lines(xs, x[, i], type='b', pch=(i - 1)*(1:nrow(x))+1, col=cols[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you try a simple example : `plot(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(5,5,5,5),type="b",pch=c(1,2,3,4))`

you will see that each point have a different pch.
So if you want different pch for each point and each lines  try to make a matrix in which line will represent the pch of each lines.

After the @mathematical.coffee answer i read the ?matplot.
And unfortunetly it's true you can not have different pch for each point but for each plot in the matplot.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me sort this :)